# How to list databases owned by rolename in postgresql

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

The code i tried in bash executed by root.

```
#!/bin/bash
su - postgres <<EOF1 
F="$(psql -d postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid WHERE rolname = 'username'")"
EOF1 
echo $F
```

It gives output as
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_authid

But when i try

```
su - postgres <<EOF1 
psql -d postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid WHERE rolname = 'username'"
EOF1
```

This prints all db of that username. Why so?

I need to store the ouput to a bash variable for further processing.

Is there any mistake or anyother way to try this out..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `$(...)` expression gets executed before the `su` part, so it will not be run as `postgres` but as the current user. This is probably better written as:

```
command="psql -d postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c \"SELECT datname FROM pg_database JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid WHERE rolname = 'username'\""
F=$( su - postgres -c "$command" )
```

You could put it all together, however:

```
F=$( su - postgres -c "psql -d postgres --tuples-only -P format=unaligned -c \"SELECT datname FROM pg_database JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid WHERE rolname = 'username'\"" )
```

I should also note that the first example that failed for you probably would not set `F` to anything you could read outside of the `su`. However, Ubuntu and I presume other modern Linux systems do not allow you to use `su` in this way. You should use, e.g., `sudo -l -u postrges` and configure `/etc/sudoers` appropriately for people to have permission to run `psql` or whatnot as the `postgres` user.