# Npgsql Exception- syntax error at or near "\"

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to execute postgresql query (\list) to get the list of databases using npsql.

```
string postgresQuery = @"\list"; 
            ICollection<Schema> schemas = new List<Schema>();
            string ConnectionString =
"Host=xxx;Username=postgres;Password=admin;Database=test;";
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(postgresQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();
   NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

While executing the query facing an issue that "syntax error at or near "\" ".   The string contains double-slash as follow (\list) instead of single-slash (\list). Please let me know if there is any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\list` isn't a valid SQL query. It's a *command* of the `psql-tool`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/show-tables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

`\list` isn't a SQL query. It's is a command of the `psql-tool`.

To get a list of all database with SQL, use the following query:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

Check [How do I list all databases and tables using psql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql)

The fields of the `pg_database` table are described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-database.html)

The database's owner is stored in the `datdba` field which references the `pg_authid` table. It's possible to find all databases owned by a user, as shown in [How to list databases owned by rolename in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691263/how-to-list-databases-owned-by-rolename-in-postgresql) with

```
SELECT datname 
FROM pg_database 
JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid 
WHERE rolname = 'username'
```

Of course, the query should be parameterized:

```
SELECT datname 
FROM pg_database 
JOIN pg_authid ON pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid 
WHERE rolname = :username
```

`pg_authid` is described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-authid.html)

Comment: Thanks for the update. This lists all the databases. But I need only the databases which are all created by the user not all the databases in the PostgreSQL.Please let me know is it possible to get the only the databases created by the user.

Comment: That's the `datdba` field. You can use this as a filter in the query, or join with the `pg_authid` table. . Check the [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-database.html)  and [pg_authid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-authid.html) documentation pages